# Strange photo appears when creating mirror

Tags: materials

I was trying to make glass, instead of it I got something like mirror, but it reflects unknown photo of trees I haven't ever seen before.[image]

Answer (score 2):

it's the standard "viewport shading > material preview" settings. it's a "nice" standard feature to simulate that your mesh in somewhere in a real place:

[image]

you can also switch the shading preview if you want using this toolbar:

[image]

Comment: Probably worth mentioning it can be turned off by checking *Scene World* :)